# Declaration and assigning value to a variable inside the scope and trying to obtain it from the ouside doesn't work while only assigning does

Tags: javascript, function, variable-declaration

After along gap, I've returned back to learning JavaScript. Here is an example of what I was trying to say in the title

```
function randomFunction(){
   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      x = i;
   }
   return x;
}

console.log(randomFunction());
```

This returns the value of `x` without any error but instead of `x = i`, if I used `let x = i;`, now x is undefined error is shown. It is defined, right? I mean `let x = 5;` defines and assigns value both at the same time, then shouldn't `let x = i` do the same? Or can I only assign values and not variables to `x` (`i` being another variable).

Plus I had another question as well, can you call a function, that first was declared as a function which accepts parameters, without providing any parameters? for example,

```
function randomFunction(x){
   return "Hello World";
}

console.log(randomFunction());
```

While testing that specific function only, I do get `Hello World` in return but when I use similar idea in other projects, I get some sort of error (I can't remember what the error was though). I just wanted to know can I do that? So that I can rule that out as not being the problem and look for bug somewhere else.

Comment: `"num1 + num2"` is a literal string.  `this.num1 + this.num2` is an expression.

Comment: It's important to explain what you mean by "working". What did you expect to happen? What did happen? In your example, variables are undefined, the code doesn't run for reasons other than you're asking about, so there are roadblocks you're putting up to people actually helping--but yes, likely the problem is you're using a string when you meant to write a JS expression (possibly among other things--who knows?). See [mcve].

Comment: `this.result = "num1 + num2";` assigns the literal string `"num1 +  num2"`, as I'm sure you've observed. You need it without the quotes if you want to actually add two numeric values. (That still won't work but I'll leave you to figure that out yourself.)

Comment: shouldn't the output should be num1 + num2 then. Still not working

Comment: Check the other comments. Plus you added the click listener to an empty `p` tag - are you clicking the button expecting it to work?

Comment: To get button element you need `document.getElementById("button")`

Comment: All of a sudden, it's working now. What an embarassment!!

Comment: @Taplar `"num1 + num2"` is also an expression.

Comment: @DavidConrad Not a mathematical one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a couple of things went wrong here:

1. Don't use the literal string `"this.num1 + this.num2"` but use the expression that take the variables and sum them together `this.num1 + this.num2`.
2. You used event listener on element that is not appeared on the screen, so how can you click it? You probably meant to use the `click` event on the id `button` and not the `demo`.
3. As a  rule of thumb, I don't think it's good to involve UI logic with your classes logic. For future use, it usually better to keep them separated.

Good Luck

```js
class Sum {
  constructor(num1, num2) {
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
  }

  add() {
    this.result = this.num1 + this.num2;
  }
}

const s = new Sum(6, 7);
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  s.add();
  displayResult(s.result);
});

function displayResult(result) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = result;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't nee the quotes in the add function and you are missing. `this` before the nums

```js
this.result = this.num1 + this.num2
```

But as you are passing in strings to the constructor it will just concatenated the values so the output will be ”ab”

If those were supposed to be variables it should be:

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 7;

const s = new Sum(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your code:

```js
class Sum {
  constructor(num1, num2) {
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
  }
          
  add() {
    this.result = this.num1 + this.num2;
  }
          
  displayResult() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = this.result;
  }
}

const s = new Sum("a", "b");
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  s.add();
  s.displayResult();
});
```

```html
    <button id="button">Click</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
```